# Как физически и логически и сохраняеться индекс в контексте РСУБД?

Tags: база-данных, postgresql, sql-server, oracle, индексы

Как физически и логически и сохраняется индекс в контексте РСУБД?
Будет ли разница только от кластерный/не кластерный или тут еще есть тонкости?
Это набор файлов? Можно ли их найти где-то в файловой системе? Есть ли между ними какая-то связь на физическом уровне (последовательны)?

похоже в случае кластерного плавно переходим к вопросу как храним таблицу, а в вопросе с не кластерным это тоже могут быть отдельные файлы?

Понимаю что есть разные RDBMS и производители могут писать о тонкостях с разным уровнем подробностей. Но возможно те кто уже давно работают в этой области видят общую картину, общие практики и подходы.